# How to add custom font in react-native v0.69.1 and react v18.0.0

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm very new to react-native, I've searched a lot about this, but it seems that `link` has been removed in react-native V0.69.1.
I don't know how to link custom fonts in my project.
project structure:

```
android
ios
src
|___assets
       |___fonts/all of my fonts with '.ttf'
```

I've created `react-native.config.js` at the root of my project with:

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/'],
};
```

and created a `<Text style={{fontFamily: 'Splash-Regular',}}>some text</Text>` but no luck!

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run `npx react-native-asset` command instead of `npx react-native link`. As the link and unlink command is deprecated for the react native version 0.69

Answer (score 3):

For me `yarn dlx react-native-asset` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your set up is ok but after Link font you need to reinstall app and then check it should work

Comment: Do you mean in the android emulator? I already did that but not worked :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this command : `react-native link` or `npx react-native link`

if this does not work try resetting the cache

- For React Native

`react-native start --reset-cache`

- for npm

`npm start -- --reset-cache`

// if still does not work you can try manually by copying the fonts file in following folder for android.

`your_app\android\app\src\main\assets\fonts`

(your_app\android\app\src\main\assets\fonts\xyz.ttf)

Comment: `react-native link` is deprecated in react-native v0.69